# Multi Job with Quartz Scheduler not running

Tags: c#, service, quartz.net

I've scheduled three job in my Service

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        private IScheduler scheduler;
        private static log4net.ILog _logFile =
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public Service()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _logFile.Info("Service OnStart");

            var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

            await scheduler.Start();
            var job = JobBuilder.Create<SearchJob>()
                .WithIdentity("SearchJob", "group1")
                .Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("SearchJobtrigger", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule(Settings.Default.SearchCronExp)
                .ForJob(job)
                .Build();

            var jobUpload = JobBuilder.Create<UploadJob>()
           .WithIdentity("UploadJob", "group1")
           .Build();

            var triggerUpload = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("TriggerUploadJob", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule(Settings.Default.UploadCronExp)
                .ForJob(jobUpload)
                .Build();

            var jobAwaiter = JobBuilder.Create<AwaiterJob>()
                .WithIdentity("AwaiterJob", "group1")
                .Build();

            var triggerAwaiterJob = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("triggerAwaiterJob", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule(Settings.Default.AwaiterCronExp)
                .ForJob(jobAwaiter)
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobUpload, triggerUpload);
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobAwaiter, triggerAwaiterJob);

            _logFile.Info("End Service OnStart");
        }

        protected override async void OnStop()
        {
            _logFile.Info("Service OnStop");
            await scheduler.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Consulting the log, I notice that the only the first job starts, the other two never start but there are no errors in the log.
I tested the service in debug and the jobs are executed correctly, while installing the service compiled in Release no, the three services have a CronExp of 1,10,30 minutes respectively between one execution and the other

Comment: where is your app hosted?

Comment: The error was due to an incorrect value of the CronExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to an incorrect value of the CronExp